# How do I solve the problem of empty backup folder when I try to restore a db in ssms

Tags: sql-server, ssms, ssms-2017

So I have some back up files in .bak formats which have been placed in the backup folder..C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Backup. but when i try to restore dabatase using restore file and file groups and just restore database in ssms, the folder is always empty.

I was expecting that the backup folder will not be empty and the .bak files will restore

Comment: When browsing the files they are local to the host, not the client. I would guess these files are on *your* `C:` *not* the host that SQL Server is on?

Comment: Also, if you are using SQL Server 15 (2019) why are you using SSMS 17, which supports SQL Server 2008-2017? It doesn't support the version of SQL Server you are using.

Comment: Another note - there is a known bug with previous versions of SSMS where it would not display the list of files in the GUI.  I would recommend upgrading to the latest version of SSMS.